# How to turn an existing, non-empty directory into a git branch of an existing non-empty git repo living in another directory

Tags: git, directory, branch

I have two directories, A & B, which differ very little in their content. A is already init'd into a git repo and has a number of local commits to its master branch. Directory B is not under SCM and it's basically just the result of manually copying all the files over from A (sans the .git directory), editing some of them, and adding some new ones. Now I want to make the contents of B a branch of the repo in A and, if possible, still host development of the new branch in directory B... but I have no idea how to accomplish that as I am a total git n00b, and don't quite yet understand its approach to SCM enough to find the answer on my own in the documentation. Any tips/pointers? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

copy A/.git into B/.git. Then do what you normally would do for the branching.

```
cd B
git branch dev
git commit -a
```

You can then sync changes like this:

```
cd A
git pull ../B dev
```

or the other way around.

Comment: Hi again romaninsh. That indeed worked pretty good! Now I have both directories init'd into git, with dir B inheriting all that was done in A's master branch & carrying from there on. The only thing I added to your instructions was switching to the new branch in B before committing the new stuff (git checkout dev). Now what I have to learn is how to inspect the work that has been done in each branch and selectively merge what I may want. If you feel like providing me with some tips, I'd appreciate it! ;) But I Know I have to do my homework and work harder at the documentation. Thanks again!

Comment: You should be able to read that in docs, but two points which were really helpful for me are `git diff dev..stable` - nitty way to compare branches and `git cherrypick` which can selectively apply patches.

Comment: git diff dev..master & git diff master..dev give nice read-outs of the bi-directional differences between both branches, thanks for that great tip too! I'll look into git cherrypick to learn how to selectively apply changes here and there. I just haven't yet had the chance of diving headlong into the documentation. Thanks a bunch for all the hand-holding help so far!

Comment: Hey! Romaninsh! Sorry again for lingering on this. Didn't notice I hadn't accepted your answer. Done now!